# Array of Arithmetic Operators in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, math

Is it possible to have an array of arithmetic operators in Swift? Something like:

```
var operatorArray = ['+', '-', '*', '/'] // or =[+, -, *, /] ?
```

I just want to randomly generate numbers and then randomly pick an arithmetic operator from the array above and perform the equation. For example,

```
var firstNum  = Int(arc4random_uniform(120))
var secondNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(120))
var equation = firstNum + operatorArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(3))] + secondNum //
```

Will the above 'equation' work?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of storing the operators as characters, since they're functions you can store them directly, maybe. Then you just execute those functions with the operands? No idea if that would work.

Comment: jshier, I tried storing them directly but it didn't work. Maybe I gotta specify the type...haven't tried that.

Comment: storing them as functions worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will - but you need to use the operators a little differently.

Single operator:

```
// declare a variable that holds a function 
let op: (Int,Int)->Int = (+)
// run the function on two arguments
op(10,10)
```

And with an array, you could use `map` to apply each one:

```
// operatorArray is an array of functions that take two ints and return an int
let operatorArray: [(Int,Int)->Int] = [(+), (-), (*), (/)]

// apply each operator to two numbers
let result = map(operatorArray) { op in op(10,10) }

// result is [20, 0, 100, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked neatly. I used  Switch statements first (worked but not very elegant) prior to getting all the replies on my question but now i'll go with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**NSExpression**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSExpression) class for doing the same.

```
var operatorArray = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
var firstNum      = Int(arc4random_uniform(120))
var secondNum     = Int(arc4random_uniform(120))
var equation      = "\(firstNum) \(operatorArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(3))]) \(secondNum)"

var exp = NSExpression(format: equation, argumentArray: [])
println(exp.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil))
```

Comment: Or you could fire a Perl script to do that ;-) Just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old fashion Object Oriented approach.

```
protocol Operation {
    func calculate(op1:Int, op2:Int) -> Int
}

class Addition : Operation {
    func calculate(op1: Int, op2: Int) -> Int {
        return op1 + op2
    }
}

class Subtraction : Operation {
    func calculate(op1: Int, op2: Int) -> Int {
        return op1 - op2
    }
}

class Multiplication : Operation {
    func calculate(op1: Int, op2: Int) -> Int {
        return op1 * op2
    }
}

class Division : Operation {
    func calculate(op1: Int, op2: Int) -> Int {
        return op1 / op2
    }
}

var operatorArray : [Operation] = [Addition(), Subtraction(), Multiplication(), Division()]

var firstNum  = Int(arc4random_uniform(120))
var secondNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(120))

var equation = operatorArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(3))].calculate(firstNum, op2: secondNum)
```

Comment: An interesting (and perhaps shorter approach) is used in the 2014 Standford iOS programming class, but instead of classes and a protocol, it uses an enum, which are quite flexible in swift.